# How to cause addProximityAlert() to create notification in status bar?

Tags: android

I have an app that notifies the user they are near something based on physical location (GPS)

Originally I did the location proximity checks manually, comparing the current lat/long to the specific target we are looking for.  If it is less than a given range, a notification is created.

After doing this all manually, I found the addProximityAlert() method which is exactly what I need.  I have a method to create the notification manually.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to bridge the gap between calling a notification manually and creating one as an intent fired by addProximityAlert()

```
public void SetupLocationListener()
{
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (useProximityAlerts)
    {
        SetupProximityAlerts(lm);
    }
    else
    {
        LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener(this, tv);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, ll);
    }
}
```

Here is my function which manually creates a notification

```
    public void AlertUser(String title, String text)
{
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

    int icon = R.drawable.icon;
    CharSequence tickerText = "Location found.";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence contentTitle = title;
    CharSequence contentText = text;
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, gps.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
    final int HELLO_ID = 1;

    mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
}
```

And here is my incomplete call to addProximityAlert()

```
lm.addProximityAlert(Double.parseDouble(allLocations[i][1]), Double.parseDouble(allLocations[i][2]), Integer.parseInt(allLocations[i][3].toString()), -1, INTENT_GOES_HERE);
```

So how do I "convert" that AlertUser() notification to a PendingIntent I can pass as a variable to addProximityAlert()?

Thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step #1: Create a `BroadcastReceiver` implementation as a public class.

Step #2: Add the receiver from step #1 to your manifest in a `<receiver>` element.

Step #3: Use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` to create a `PendingIntent` pointing to that receiver.

Step #4: Pour your raise-the-`Notification` logic in the receiver's `onReceive()` method, using the supplied `Context` to get your `NotificationManager` and so on.

Step #5: Have a beer (or the recreational refreshment of your choice, so long as it is legal in your jurisdiction).

Comment: I'm attempting this.  In the manifest receiver element, what does the Intent-Filter action:name point to?  A class?  A specific method?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Kevin: "what does the Intent-Filter action:name point to?" -- you do not need an `<intent-filter>` at all. Just use the `Intent` constructor that takes the Java class: `new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class)`. BTW, your beer is getting lonely.

Comment: Thank you sir.  I shall pour my Sam Adams cherry promptly.

Comment: One of the parameters of getBroadcast() is INTENT.  Do I need to create this?  What should it point to?

Comment: @Kevin: "Do I need to create this?" -- yes. "What should it point to?" -- your `BroadcastReceiver`, as mentioned in step #3, with syntax as shown in my last comment.

Comment: Wow. I'm an idiot. Completely missed that.  Fortunately through my own work I figured that out.  Sort of satisfying.  Thank you very much.